# JPA Repository findAll where creationDate exceeds set time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, repository

I am developing an Application, that uses a scheduler to check the Database for any Data older than a set amount of days and delete that data. I'm running into a problem planning this, as I'm struggling to find concrete Information about how this is done in way conforming to good practices. I'm unsure how I can use a JPA Repository to findAll exceeding a certain Date.

```
@Repository
public interface MyDataRepository extends JpaRepository<Data, String> {

//how to add: WHERE Date exceeds 10 days
findAll();

}
```

I would appreciate any help / pointers.

Comment: Does it help you? https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa

Comment: @BuildSlayer I was snooping around there a little and if I use that approach (if my understanding is correct) I would use a manual query to accomplisch my goal. However i was unsure if that is the correct approach and am also unsure how to select data exceeding a certain age using this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to calculate the 10 days in the service method and pass the calculated day as a parameter:

```
@Query("select d from Data d where a.createdAt <= :d10DaysAgo")
List<Article> findAllWithCreationDateTimeBefore(LocalDate d10DaysAgo)
```

More on this here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query-by-date